# Deallocating Dynamic Memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I recently did a school homework assignment and lost points, in the comment the grader said that I didn't deallocate the pointers correctly.
Below is the code I sent, I would just like to know how it would look to deallocate the pointers correctly?

```
/*Student: Daniel
 *Purpose: To reverse a string input using
 *pointers.
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    char *head = new char, *tail = new char;
    char temp;
    //Get the string from the user that will be reversed
    cout << "Enter in a string that you want reversed: ";
    getline(cin, input);
    //Create and copy the string into a character array
    char arr[input.length()];
    strcpy(arr, input.c_str());
    //Set the points of head/tail to the front/back of array, respectably
    head = &arr[0]; tail = &arr[input.length()-1];
    for(int i=0; i<input.length()/2; i++) {
        temp = *(tail);
        *tail = *head;
        *head = temp;
        tail --; head ++;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    //********MY PROBLEM AREA*************
    delete head; delete tail;
    head = NULL; tail = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char arr[input.length()];` -- That's not legal C++.  For variable sized arrays, you actually *do* need dynamic allocation.  Even if it was legal, it's one character less than necessary.  You need space for the null terminator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So take a look here...

```
char *head = new char, *tail = new char;
```

And then...

```
//Set the points of head/tail to the front/back of array, respectably
head = &arr[0]; tail = &arr[input.length()-1];
```

You reassigned what `head` and `tail`point to, so you're not actually deleting the right things when you call delete.  In fact, I'm surprised you don't crash.

Really you can probably just do:

```
char *head = NULL; char* tail = NULL;
```

and then not delete anything since you won't have anything dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So it would have been better to to initialize them to "NULL" instead of "new char"? And there won't even be a need for deletion of the pointers?

Comment: Yes - in this case that works.  There are other instances where working with only stack allocated memory is insufficient.